# My crond job doesn't work as expected, why?

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I created a shell script to check a tomcat instance status. If the instance is not started, then start it:

```
if [ `ps -ef | grep 'travelco' | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ];then
sudo /home/q/tools/bin/restart_tomcat.sh /home/www/travelco/
else
  echo 'travelco started'
fi
```

Then I tested the script and it worked well. But after I added it as a crond job, this script didn't work as expected.
I used `crontab -e`, and added

```
*/1 * * * * /home/yuliang.jin/travelcoCheck.sh
```

After that, even though I can see the script executed in the crontab log(`sudo tail -f /var/log/cron`), the tomcat instance was not started. Why?

Comment: You dont need to give /1 . By default cron will run per minute if u use * . So  use `* * * * * /home/yuliang.jin/travelcoCheck.sh
`

Comment: Thanks, but why the script didn't execute as expected? I mean instance was started. But when I execute "/home/yuliang.jin/travelcoCheck.sh", it could be started.@jQuery.PHP.Magento.com

Comment: Do you mean you hit the Sh file directly in Shell and press enter ,it runs ?

Comment: You said `the tomcat instance was not started.` , then start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If there is any other option, don't sudo in a cron job.
2. `travelcoCheck.sh` will be matched by the `grep travelco` and is not cancelled by the `grep -v grep`, so `wc -l` will be at least 1 always. So `restart_tomcat.sh` will not run.

(As a side note: whether or not your `ps`-parsing stack gets caught by `ps` is something of a dark art and is full of corner cases and race conditions and generally difficult to get to work right. Stuff like this is why `dbus` was invented.)

Comment: Yes, I changed the comparison part to be "if [ `ps -ef | grep java | grep travelco | wc -l` -eq 0 ]", this time it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a `sudo` in your script but are you sure that your current user has the permission to execute `/home/q/tools/bin/restart_tomcat.sh` without password authentication?

You should add the script to `/etc/sudoers` to allow your current user to execute the script without password, or you can just `sudo crontab -e` to run the script as root (and don't forget to delete `sudo` in your script if you do so).